# Derivation of $P(A\mid B)=P(A\mid T)P(T\mid B)+P(A\mid T^c)P(T^c\mid B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A,P)$ be a probability space and $A,B,T\in \mathcal A$. I want to verify the identity 
  $$P(A\mid B)=P(A\mid T)P(T\mid B)+P(A\mid T^c)P(T^c\mid B)$$

If I draw a probability tree then I can clearly see where the formula comes from by following the event $A$ from the top.

[image]

However, I would much rather like to prove the identity above using explicit formulas. I tried the following:
$$P(A\mid T)P(T\mid B)+P(A\mid T^c)P(T^c\mid B)$$
$$= \frac{P(A\cap T)}{P(T)}\cdot\frac{P(T\cap B)}{P(B)} + \frac{P(A\cap T^c)}{P(T^c)}\cdot\frac{P(T^c\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
$$= \cdots$$

But here is where I am stuck. How can I show that this is equal to $P(A\mid B)$ ?

Comment: No chance this can hold. Who told you it does?

Comment: @Did I found the formula in the book "Heard on the Street" by Timothy Falcon Crack (in the solution of question 4.10, page 222). He used it for a particular example. So I was wondering whether it was true for general events $A,B,T$.

Comment: The author (probably meant and) should have written P(W|2)=P(W|T,2)P(T|2)+P(W|Tc,2)P(Tc|2), which is classical Bayes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your identity ought to say:
$$
P(A\mid B)=P(A\mid T\cap B)P(T\mid B)+P(A\mid T^c\cap B)P(T^c\mid B).
$$

I suspect there was at least a tacit assumption that $T\subseteq B$ and $T^c\subseteq B$, so that $P(T)=P(T\cap B)$.  That would imply $P(B)=1$.  In that case, changing $P(T)$ to $P(T\cap B)$ you your denominators, or changing $P(T\cap B)$ to $P(T)$ in your numerators, would be correct and results in a cancellation.

Comment: Yes, this resolves my issue. Thanks!